# Are Objective-C UUIDs compatible with .NET

Tags: .net, objective-c, guid, uuid

Is a UUID (GUID) created using CFUUIDCreate in objective-c compatible with GUIDs created within the Microsoft .NET framework.

i.e. if I build an iOS system that generates ids using CFUUIDCreate will I always be able to use these in a .NET context?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A UUID/GUID is just a 128-bit integer. As such, it is inherently platform-agnostic.

When represented as strings, it seems that both `CFUUIDCreateString()` and `System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString()` use nearly the same format.

The only difference is that `CFUUIDCreateString()` uses uppercase letters to represent hex digits (`"6027EC11-8084-4678-A250-53D534AEFD4A"`) while the .NET version uses lowercase letters (`"9245fe4a-d402-451c-b9ed-9c1a04247482"`) by default.

Comment: Thanks.  Does that mean that absolutely any 128-bit integer can always be converted to a .NET guid?

Comment: I'm not a .NET programmer but look at the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx. You can create a `System.Guid` by passing arbitrary 128 bits (in various formats) to the constructor. It's just a (very big) number, nothing more.